# Generate unique identifier in rails helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-slider

I have this rails helper `_fields_answer.html.erb`

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <%= answerf.text_area :content, placeholder: "Answer", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%= answerf.hidden_field :question_number, value: qn %>

    <div class="col-xs-2 buttonProjDel">
      <%= answerf.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields btn btn-danger btn-xs buttonProjDelBut" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <% st = Time.now.strftime("%I%M%S%p") %>
      <%= answerf.text_field :scale, id: 'slf'+st , type: 'text',
                     data: {'slider-id' => 'scale',
                            'slider-min' => '0',
                            'slider-max' => '10',
                            'slider-step' => '1',
                            'slider-value' => '5' } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $('<%= '#slf'+st %>').slider()
  </script>
</fieldset>
```

And I render this helper dynamically, but I just can have the slider in the first one. So I tried to had a different `Id` for each one, but I am not able to do it. 
With the code above I always get the same `Id`, even using the `Time`.

[image]

[image]

Why is the time used in `id` always the same?

There is another way to do this? I want to have a slide for each answer.

**Edit:**

The code that renders the helper:
In `projects.js.coffee`

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

In application_helper.rb

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, locals)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id

    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render("fields_" + association.to_s.singularize, answerf: builder, qn: locals[:qn])
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields " + locals[:class], data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view rendering was done within a second! hence the reason you are seeing the same `id` value for all `inputs`.

The statement below will have the same value for 60 seconds.

```
st = Time.now.strftime("%I%M%S%p")
```

As it appears you want the slider to be on each input, I would recommend using either a data attribute or simply a css class.  An example using css class would be:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= answerf.text_field :scale, class: 'has-slider', type: 'text',
                     data: {'slider-id' => 'scale',
                            'slider-min' => '0',
                            'slider-max' => '10',
                            'slider-step' => '1',
                            'slider-value' => '5' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Say we assign class `has-slider`, we could then use this class selector and execute `slider()` on the matched elements in javascript as:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/input_slider.js.coffee

$ ->
  # Execute slider on all inputs with has-slider css class
  $('input.has-slider').slider()
```

And, you seem to know why you have slider only on the first input; This is because all your inputs have same `id` value and DOM selection retrieves the first match.  `id`s need to be unique within a document.

**Update**:

As you're adding input elements within the dom after page load, the `$('input.has-slider').slider()` call made on `app/assets/javscripts/input_slider.js.coffee` would not work.  It would only work for elements already present in the DOM.  In order to make it work for elements added after DOM load, you can use jQuery `on()` method.

You could trigger some custom event and call `slider()` method as follows:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  ...
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time)).trigger('show-slider')
  ..
```

Then you will listen on the `show-slider` event and call `slider()` as:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/input_slider.js.coffee

$ ->
  # Execute slider on all inputs with has-slider css class
  $('input.has-slider').slider()

  $(document).on 'show-slider', (event) ->
    $(input.has-slider').slider()
```

Hope this clears any confusion.

Comment: Thanks @vee I have tried with the class too, but I have the same result, it just work for the first slide. It is strange because all of them have the same class. Any other idea?

Comment: I see remove buttons, I'm assuming you also have a plus button somewhere on the page that's hidden.  Are you generating these text fields using javascript?

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery. I have updated the question, with more details. The render that uses the helper is in the application_helper file and works with the jQuery code that I posted above.

Comment: I don't understand why the render is done within a second if I press the Add Answer button with some delay. Can you explain me? I supposed that was some rails magic/efficiency... but I don't really understand why.

Comment: This is a dynamic nested form. I have the model Project and the model Answer. And then I have some questions that can have multiple answers. The questions are just text in the form, the answers are associated with the model Project.

Comment: Sorry @marcpt, the title of your question is completely wrong given the actual question.  I would suggest you rephrase it so that you get better eyes.  Please see my update.  Good luck.